# Serial connection of Processing and Arduino

Tags: arduino, processing, serial-communication

I'm trying to make a serial connection from processing to arduino. The idea is that when I press "a", the speaker from Arduino will produce a sound and the same goes with another key pressed but with a different note. However, I'm a bit stuck with the codes. Can anyone let me know what is the problem of my codes?

Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort; 
int val; // Data received from the serial port

void setup()
{
size(200, 200);
String portName = Serial.list()[0]; 
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
}

 void keyPressed(){
   if (key == 'a'){
     myPort.write(1); 
   }
   if (key == 'd'){
     myPort.write(2); 
   }  
 }
 void keyReleased(){
   myPort.write(0);
 }
```

Arduino code:

```
char val; // Data received from the serial port
int speakerPin = 8;

void setup() {
pinMode(speakerPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
while (Serial.available()) { 
val = Serial.read(); 
}
if (val == '1') {  
tone(speakerPin, 262, 200); 
} else if (val == '2'){
tone(speakerPin, 523, 200); 
}
delay(100); 
}
```

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are so close!

The issue is on the Arduino side you're checking characters, however, on the Processing side you're sending the actual values, not the ASCII characters.

```
1 != '1' (49)
2 != '2' (50)
```

In Processing, simply use the `char` type single quote symbols:

```
myPort.write('1');
```

...

```
myPort.write('2');
```

(which is the same as `myPort.write(49);` for '1', `myPort.write(50);` for '2')

Alternatively you can change the way you're checking on Arduino side to not use chars to be consistent with how you're sending from Processing. e.g.

```
if (val == 1)
```

(instead of `if (val == '1')`).

Comment: Also, consider sending the character of the keyboard key that is pressed instead of translating 'a' into '1', 'b' into '2', etc. Instead, send the key character ('a'), and in the Arduino code, check for an 'a': `if val=='a'`, etc. Then the Processing code can just be: `void keyPressed(){myPort.write(key);}`.